# Origin of Firefox traffic when running on a remote machine

Tags: ip, x11forwarding

When I connect to a remote host:

```
desktop$ ssh -X user@remote
```

and start firefox:

```
remote$ firefox &
```

I expect firefox to be run on `remote` and also all traffic should be sent to internet using `remote`'s ip. This is not happening. Is there any ssh option to make it act that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell firefox on the remote machine to not worry about your currently running instance. Use the cli arg of -no-remote to do this:

remote$ firefox -no-remote &

Answer (score 1):

Given the behaviour you're experiencing, I find it likely that Firefox is detecting the existence of a session already running on the X server (`desktop`) and telling that session to open a new window.

This would give the behaviour you're experiencing.

Otherwise, it should behave exactly as you describe. Firefox (the X client) doesn't care where the X server that it's talking to is located; all traffic originated from Firefox comes from the host that it's running on.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (and it might provide better performance) is to set up an SOCKS proxy using ssh. For example

ssh -D 8675 remote

And then set your local browser to use localhost:8675 as the proxy.